# sql authenatication

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2005, phpmyadmin

I am developing a application where the data will go and store in the database after completing my application database will be handle by the system administrator of the company he may change the data I have problem like the system administrator will take care of the database once we develop the application the database will be handled by him now i want to restrict him from modifying data like inserting,updating,deleting data from database

how can i do that

any1 help me on this

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new user:

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html

You can grant and revoke privileges on your database by using the

`GRANT` and `REVOKE` keywords

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html
And:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/revoke.html